# return max value from a list that has multiple elements python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that has 2 elements in each tuple, one element being a string(fileid) and the other being a int(amount of words)

```
('ca01', 715), ('ca02', 784), ('ca03', 690), ('ca04', 756), ('ca05', 625), ('ca06', 705)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to return both elements in the tuple based on the max value of the second element, for example here, the max value in this list is the second elements in the second tuple "784". However, I would like to return both elements "('ca02', 784)"

Comment: Use `max(lst, key=itemgetter(1))`. See `help(max)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `max()` function witht a proper key:

```
>>> lst = [('ca01', 715), ('ca02', 784), ('ca03', 690), ('ca04', 756), ('ca05', 625), ('ca06', 705)]
>>> 
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> max(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
('ca02', 784)
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this without using from operator import itemgetter?? see update

Comment: @seus What you mean by another way? Do you want to get the maximum item based on a different logic?

Comment: @seus You could use `max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: @Kasramvd just wondering if there is an alternate way besides importing another library

Comment: @seus Yes, that's what  OrangeFlash81 mentioned in previous command.